# Why didn't Voldemort personally seek out his followers?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Why did he need to wait in Albania?

True, Auror's were searching for him, but he could hide himself in animals, could he not? If I were him, I'd hide myself in, say, birds, and fly right to Lucius Malfoy's house.

Comment: Not sure, but it's probably a demonstration of power and loyalty.  Like in the movie, he takes note of who _doesn't_ show up following his call; those people he now considers "traitors" and will probably do something nasty to them later.

Comment: Voldemort in spirit-only form is very weak. He can’t risk showing himself to a Death Eater who might turn him in. Especially not someone like Lucius Malfoy. – @Tim: The question is about the phase where Voldemort is “less than the meanest ghost”, not about after his return to a body.

Comment: Didn't he say the animals didn't last long?  Be a bit risky to start off on a migration in the body of a bird that might drop dead any minute. :-)

Comment: Were you going to return and accept an answer, perhaps? That way this is marked as solved.

Answer (score 8):

- **He was very weak.**

> Aaah... pain beyond pain, my friends; nothing could have prepared me for it. I was ripped from my body, I was less than spirit; less than the meanest ghost... but still, I was alive.
>   <sub>-*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 33</sub>

He was very weak; it would take effort to find a Death Eater who was still loyal and not in Azkaban.

- **Animals didn't last long.**

> I sometimes inhabited animals - snakes, of course, being my preference - but I was little better off inside them than as pure spirits, for their bodies were ill adapted to perform magic... and my possession of them shortened their lives; none of them lasted long.

So would *you* want to risk having your host die over the ocean where it would be almost impossible for someone to find you?

- **He didn't know if any of them were still loyal.**

> ...and I had given up hope, now, that any of my Death Eaters cared what had become of me...

So there were several reasons why he didn't go looking for them.

---

There's also no reason to assume he could *talk* while possessing an animal. And even if he could, would *you* believe if a little bird flew up to you and claimed to be the Dark Lord? :P

Answer (score -4):

He thinks so highly of himself he does what he wants. His way of regaining strength and seeing who still followed him. But why would he fear death if he still had that many Horcruxes is a better question...